# Slash in cmis:name and cmis:contentStreamFilename

Tags: cmis, documentum

The [CMIS 1.1 specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/CMIS-v1.1.html) says:

> **2.1.5.3 Paths**
>   A folder hierarchy MAY be represented in a canonical notation such as path.
>   [...]
>   A pathSegment token MUST not include a ’/’ character.
>   It is repository speciﬁc how a repository chooses the value for pathSegment. Repositories might choose to use cmis:name or content stream ﬁlename for pathSegment token.

But, I was able to create the document below in a Documentum 7.1.0000.0146 server:

[image: Documentum in CMIS Workbench]

As you can see, both `cmis:name` and `cmis:contentStreamFilename` contain a slash. Actually, it seems that `cmis:contentStreamFilename` becomes whatever `cmis:name` is (plus the extension).

Is this a bug in Documentum's CMIS implementation?

While this server replies correctly to "normal" `getObjectByPath` requests with `cmis:name` path elements, is there any way to use `getObjectByPath` for the object in the screenshot above? Or is `getObjectByPath` unusable with such a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe it is a bug in Documentum's CMIS implementation (meaning, it's a bug to *allow* the slash to be part of `cmis:name` and `cmis:contentStreamFileName`). I found [this bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CMIS-232) from the Apache Chemistry Jira project, where it seems a similar bug was fixed. Some comments that shed some light on the issue:

> Given the following path to an object:
>   /a/b/c/d.pdf
>
> The path segment tokens are "a", "b", "c", and "d.pdf".
>
> The getObjectByPath method does assume that you will pass it a path comprised of path segment tokens separated by forward slashes. This is how CMIS defines a "path" per the spec.

...and...

> Repository might use cmis:name for pathSegment token, however, if repository doesn't use cmis:name as pathSegment token, this case will fail obviously.
>
> There're some possible scenarios that cmis:name is not used as pathSegment token:
>
> 1) Content stream file name is used rather than cmis:name as it is described in the spec.
>
> 2) Repository supports to create document with same cmis:name in a folder, which means it is inevitable to use other value rather than cmis:name as its pathSegment since "The pathSegment token for each item MUST uniquely identify the item in the folder" according to the spec.

I don't know Documentum specifically, so whether this bug would manifest when fetching the object is a coin toss. Have you considered using [CMIS Workbench](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/tools/dev-tools-workbench.html) to run a simple CMIS query to find it using one of those properties? If it worked, I'd be pretty confident (though not 100%) it would work with `getObjectByPath`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there are much restrictions on object names in a Documentum repository.
If you want to apply a business rule to ensure no object names are created with the '/' character then have a look at the BOF framework.

Comment: I know that Documentum allows slashes in object names, but my question was about how to handle such cases from the point of view of a CMIS client. Anyway, thanks for the business rule workaround!